# Change fixed size to be width or height in web page depending on picture orientation

Tags: html, css

I am creating a site from scratch, without tools, and need to solve a simple problem. 
I have this html code for an image:

```
.preview img {
    border:  4px solid #444;
    padding: 1px;
    width:   600px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 130px;
    right: 150px;
}
```

However, since some pictures are horizontal and some are vertical, I would like the `600px` to be the longest edge, not always the width.

Is this possible?

Comment: Not in CSS, no. You will need JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by adding some javascript inline to the image element. 
Setup the css style for horizontal photos, then add the style for vertical images inline:

```
<img src="http://..." onload="if(this.width<this.height) { this.style.width='inherit';this.style.height='600px'};">
```